# Why would you simultaneously return from a function and assign to an argument?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

In a codebase I'm working on I keep encountering code like this:

```
std::string& getSomeValue(std::string& str)
{
    str = "Hello World!";
    return str;
}
```

Is there any benefit to writing this over:

```
std::string getSomeValue()
{
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

I appreciate that there is no string construction in the function, but the many disadvantages outway that small benefit. Especially since elision and moving should remove most of the overhead.

It leads to undefined behaviour if called as

```
std::string s = getSomeValue(s);
```

It's untidy to write the following, and s now can't be const:

```
std::string s; 
getSomeValue(s);
```

You can't pass a temporary, e.g.

```
std::string s = getSomeValue("");
```

Comment: Seems like it was meant to avoid creating unnecessary string objects. This code looks like it may be from an earlier version of the language which wasn't as good at avoid those. You might not need this kind of optimization anymore.

Comment: @iwans -- Note that many of the standard C-string functions (like `strcat`) work this way (using pointers).

Comment: A possibility is that it can be used in streams, for example: `std::cout << getSomeValue(s) << '\n';` It will modify the variable and pass it to the output stream without performing an extra copy.

Comment: It would be useful to use this for chaining functions..

Comment: the UB case is not really an argument against this function. If someone writes `std::string s = getSomeValue(s);` they will also write `int x = x;` which basically has the same problem

Answer (score 3):

You can't change `std::string& getSomeValue(std::string& str)` into `std::string getSomeValue()`. That would break the API and ABI. Existing code using that function would need to be changed.

So one benefit is maintaining API/ABI compatibility. As to why this was written this way, it's probably pre-C++11 code.

However, an overload could be introduced, keeping the old function and introducing the new, better form. The old one can then be marked deprecated:

```
[[deprecated("unsafe, use getSomeValue() without argument instead")]]
std::string& getSomeValue(std::string& str);
```

Use of the old function will then generate a compiler warning and the code can be changed over time to adopt the new function.